# Prove that a set infinite if it has infinite proper subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Suppose that $A$ is an infinite set and $A \subsetneq C$. Use the definition of "infinite set" to prove that $C$ is infinite also. I am trying to prove that $C$ is infinte.

> **Definition** *(Infinite set)*. $A$ is a *infinite* set if there is some proper subset $B \subsetneq A$ such that the elements of $A$ can be put into a one-to-one corresponence with the elements of $B$. Also, we say that a set $A$ is *finite* if it is not infinite.

Comment: $A$ is infinite, so there exists such a $B \subset A$. Now consider the set $D = B \cup (C \backslash A)$. Is $D$ a proper subset of $C$? And can you find a one-to-one correspondence between $C$ and $D$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a proper subset $A'\subset A$ such that there exists a bijection $f:A\to A'$.

Define $g:C\to A'\cup(C-A)$, $g(x)=x$ if $x\notin A$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in A$.

Surely you can show that $A'\cup(C-A)$ is a proper subset of $C$ and that $g$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove before

> **Lemma.** Let $X$ be a finite set, and let $Y$ a subset of $X$. Then $Y$ is finite.

*Hint:* If $f\colon X\to Z$ is a function from $X$ to $Z\subseteq X$, then it cannot be a bijection for any susbet $Z$ of $X$.